# Backbone: Access to Model from Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In [Addy Osmani's *Developing Backbone.js Applications*](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/), he uses a `nextOrder()` function in his `TodoList` collection to find the highest ordered item in that collection and return it, like so:

```
nextOrder: function() {
    if ( !this.length ) {
        return 1;
    }

    return this.last().get('order') + 1;
},
```

Doing the same thing is not working for me. I'm trying to make a list of games, so I've got below a `Game` model and a `Games` collection:

```
var Games = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('gameslist-backbone'),

    nextOrder: function () {
        if (!this.length) {
            return 1;
        }

        return this.last().get('id') + 1;
    }
});

var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 'Untitled'
    }
});
```

I then initialize both...

```
var app = {};

$(function () {
    app.game = new Game();
    app.games = new Games({ model: app.game });
});
```

...and play around in the console to see what I can discover:

```
app.games.length      //=> 1
app.games.nextOrder() //=> NaN
```

The one item in `app.games` at this point is the model's `defaults`. Why? The collection should be blank at this point, right? And assuming so, why does `nextOrder()` return `NaN` rather than 2?

I can get this to work a little differently if I initialize the collection as `app.games = new Games();` and set `model: app.game` as an attribute in the collection. nextOrder() then works, but:

```
app.games.create({ 'Name': 'Monopoly' });
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new this.model(attrs, options)')
```

At this point, `nextOrder()` works perfectly fine, but the collection doesn't seem to be interfacing with the model since I'm interpreting that error as 'What model do you want me to create? I don't know about any.'

Thanks for answering what I expect to be a very dumb question :|

Comment: The `model` property of a collection should be a model *class*, not an *instance* and it is usually part of the collection definition. Works fine if you set things up properly: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4ZvLe/

Comment: So helpful and useful. Not sure how I missed that. Does indeed work fine if you set things up properly. Thanks for showing me the way.

Comment: `model` as an instance property is common with views though so you'll see a lot of things like `var v = new SomeView({ model: app.game })`.